# copying and pasting multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Problem. I want to copy the entire column which has values inside from a worksheet and paste it to anotherworksheet. I have the following code which sort of does this;

```
with copySheet.Range("A2:A400")
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
end with
```

Here i copy the Column A values until 400th row, i would like this to be variable, so i would like to copy until the final value in that column and paste it to Column B.

Additionally, if i would like to copy Column B and paste it to Column C, with the same code that i wrote above exchanged with B and C values as follows;

```
with copySheet.Range("B2:B400")
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
end with
```

This Code after used the first one above, does not pastes the Column to Column A. Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable to capture the last row of data in the desired Copy column, then use that in your `With` statement.

```
Sub test()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set copySheet = Sheets("copySheet")
Set pasteSheet = Sheets("pasteSheet")

'Determine last row of Column A in copySheet
lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With copySheet.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

'Determine last row of Column B in copySheet
lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With copySheet.Range("B2:B" & lRow)
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

You could then take it a step further and assign a `Long` variable to account for how many columns you need to copy, and add a `For` loop to go through each one.

Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you copy the entire sheet then insert a new column in front of Column A on the `pasteSheet`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this? it is a little brute force....for the second question you can change B and C

```
Columns("A").Select
Selection.copy
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```